# Can I make navigation menu item text to be different than other items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-navigationview

I'm using `NavigationView` and menu on my app.
I want one of the menu items to to be in different color (Icon and text).

I can make the icon show other color using `setItemIconTintList(null)` and using icons in the required colors.
Is there a way to make a single menu item text color to be different?

Comment: did my answer hped you? If yes, then pls accept my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inspired by [DevTest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319627/devtest)'s answer, I've eventually used `SpannableString` for setting a text with a specific color.
I've created a util method for it:

```
public static CharSequence getSpannableColorString (String text, int color) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(text);
    spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color),0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    return spanString;
}
```

Then used it for setting my `MenuItem`'s title:

```
MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.myItem);
menuItem.setTitle(getSpannableColorString(getString(R.string.itemText), getColor(R.color.itemColor)));
```

Comment: its nice to upvote an answer if it really helped you :-)

Comment: I think the SpannableString option is better... thanks

Comment: sure it is. But if my answer helped you in anyway, upvoting it helps me too :-)

Comment: No issues abt that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
//Change to your NavigationView Id
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);            

//change R.id.menu_item to your id
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff3824'>Settings</font>"));
```

Comment: Well, this indeed does the trick. nice!
However it feels like a hack. I'm waiting to see if there could be a more standard way for doing it.

Comment: there are no other standard way in navigationview that I know of. You can change the color of comeplete menus items, but AFAIK, not individual items.